# How to use variable-width font in HTML <pre> field

Tags: html, text, formatting, pre

I wish to display pre-formatted text as stored in a MySQL database but want to avoid displaying the text in the fixed-width font that `<pre>` imposes

Or am I mistaken that  imposes any particular font but merely defaults to fixed-width?

Answer (score 1):

The same way you use a variable width font in any other element: With the CSS font-family property.

```css
pre { font-family: helvetica, sans-serif; }
```

```html
<pre>Hello
    World</pre>
```

Answer (score -2):

Found a solution .... adding `white-space: pre-wrap;` to the CSS style for the element displaying the text achieved the result I was looking for